# Hide credentials in a public repo, which is being used to deploy live

Tags: git, github, heroku, netlify

What are best practices in hiding credentials, such as API keys or database credentials, in a public repo such as GitHub? My go-to solution is to have a config file which stores the credentials, then add a gitignore file to not include the config file during push.

The caveat is this repo is being used to deploy with every push, e.g. Netlify or Heroku. So a Netlify / Heroku website is online from the repo push. In this case, if there is an API call or database request, the credentials would need to be in the public repo, as this is the "production folder".

I've heard of Travis CI, and that it could build after a GitHub push, but I have not looked into it much. How do other projects use their credentials when deploying from a public repository?

Comment: With Heroku, you'd use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the way that folks pass secrets to their code is through the environment, which is considered a best practice.  Here's why:

- Secrets in the environment are never written to disk, so there's much less accidental risk of discovery or disclosure.
- Secrets in the environment are only visible to other processes with the same user ID, which is helpful when deploying to hardware.

If your credentials are small enough, you can use the secret store or environment store of whatever provider you're using.  All major CI providers have this and I expect most major hosting sites do as well; I know Heroku does.  Things like SSH keys which *must* be files can be written to disk from the environment, ideally into a temporary directory which is cleaned up.

If you're deploying to your own infrastructure, generally you'll have some encrypted secret store for this purpose.  Vault is a common one.

If you need credentials that are for development, you can structure your code such that there's a safe default (like the hard-coded phrase `secret`) for development use if no variable is set, or you can provide a set of fallbacks in development and test code.  Some projects also use `.env` files, although this requires additional code which some people don't want to install.

If you have huge credentials that you cannot store in your secret store, you can [encrypt them and store the passphrase in the secret store](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets).

Comment: Thanks @bk2204 !  Environments makes sense, and I've heard of secrets, just have not looked into it yet. Will check this out